# Strange behaviour of Solarized-theme in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, themes

I installed the Solarized theme through package-install RET solarized-theme, and it went largely well but .org files have a strange appearance:

[image]

Note how it hides the line numbers. Here is how it looks on other files:

[image]

How do I make it so that org files have the same appearance as other files? Please note that I am new to this so I may not understand some things that are obvious to more experienced Emacs hackers.

My init.el file:

```
(package-initialize)

;;settings files location
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/settings")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
;;import settings from other files
(require 'general-settings)

;;theme loading
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (solarized-dark)))
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("8aebf25556399b58091e533e455dd50a6a9cba958cc4ebb0aab175863c25b9a4" default)))
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (solarized-theme))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)
;;ido
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode t)(package-initialize)

(setq package-archives
      '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
       ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
       ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))

;;org-mode

;;markdown
(autoload 'markdown-mode "markdown-mode"
   "Major mode for editing Markdown files" t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\(.text\\|.markdown\\|.md\\)'" . markdown-mode))
(setq markdown-enable-math t) ;;enables math functions
```

my settings file (some useful things I borrowed from a friend):

```
;;------------------------------;;
;;   Global Editor    Settings  ;;
;;------------------------------;;

(setq current-language-environment "English") ;; Language
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t) ;; Don't show the start-up Screen

(menu-bar-mode 0) ;; Toggle menu bar

(require 'tool-bar) ;; Toggle toolbar
(tool-bar-mode 0)

(global-hl-line-mode 1) ;; Highlight line with cursorx

(if window-system (scroll-bar-mode 0)) ;; Toggle scroll bar
(require 'mwheel) ;; Toggle mouse wheel support for scrolling
(mouse-wheel-mode 1)

(transient-mark-mode 1) ;; Transient-Mark Mode (highlight selection

(global-linum-mode t) ;; Display line number at left
(line-number-mode 1)
(column-number-mode 1)

;; Text decoration


;; Window resizing bindings
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<left>") 'shrink-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<right>") 'enlarge-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<down>") 'shrink-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<up>") 'enlarge-window)


(provide 'general-settings)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those with this problem, I solved it as follows:

Solarized theme has a toggle to scale font sizes of org headings. Disable that with this line in the init file to fix the issue:

```
(setq solarized-scale-org-headlines nil)
```

Comment: Did you try nlinum instead of linum for line numbers?

Comment: For me, the font used in the headings is still different.  Would be nice to be able to prevent that too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set solarized-scale-org-headlines to nil before loading the theme

```
(setq solarized-scale-org-headlines nil)
(load-theme 'solarized-zenburn t)
```